# Discord substringing a message

Tags: c#, discord

I'm currently working on a discord bot and I tried to make a command where you type something, and the bot will say that back to you, only without the !say part. As you can see here, I used a substring. It seems that when the downloaded message gets turned into a string, it doens't function like one.
When I put the commmand in discord, it just doesn't work. I don't get an error message. It just doesn't respond.

```
private void RegisterSayCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("say")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                string messagestosay, message_b;
                int message_sub;
                Message[] message_a;
                message_a = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);
                message_b = message_a.ToString();
                message_sub = message_b.Length;
                messagestosay = message_b.Substring(4, message_sub);

                await e.Channel.SendMessage(messagestosay);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download messages, it returns a `Message[]` datatype. And you cannot convert it to string directly to get the message.

Instead, use `e.Args[0]`, it basically returns a `string`datatype, and it contains the message w/o the command.
For example: I have a code inside my command, `string x = e.Args[0];`, and I type '!say this'. "this" will be the value of `x`.

So effectively, you won't even need to substring it too! All you literally have to do is `string message_a = e.Args[0];` and make it send `message_a` directly back to the channel!

Edit :
Now to allow the bot to take in input, behind your `.Do(async...` , add a `.Parameter("user", ParameterType.Unparsed)`. This allows your bot to take additional input(s) from the user.

Comment: I understand the method, but I don't understand how to use it in the code.
please explain further how you used it in your code :)

Comment: `string messageSay = e.Args[0];  await e.Channel.SendMessage(messageSay);` , that would literally be the code inside the command function. **First**, try this code. **Second**, notice how your messageSay is a string, and how you don't need to substring out the command. **Third**, from your old code, send `message_b` to the text channel, notice how weird it is. **Finally**, here is the part : Your old code doesn't work because there is no way to directly convert a `Message[]` datatype to string, that is because it's an array, and also Discord.NET doesn't have that sort of function yet.

Comment: [link](https://puu.sh/uLiVk/c0a14d0478.gif)
it does not seem to work :/

Comment: @SugoiSheep did you read the edited part? `.Parameter("user", ParameterType.Unparsed)` behind `.Do(async...` . It basically allows your bot to read a string to the end and take it as an input. So you basically do `Commands.CreateCommands("command").Parameter("user", ParameterType.Unparsed).Do(async (e) => {/*code*/});`

Comment: doesn't seem like [EventArgs](https://puu.sh/uOCSy/9dee324dc7.png) agrees with you :/

Comment: @SugoiSheep `e.Args[0]` and `EventArgs[0]` is 2 different things.